# Cannot print on new Ubuntu 20.04 installation

Tags: drivers, printing, hp, canon

I have 2 printers: a Canon G2400 and a HP Laserjet P1005.

Both of these machines are connected by USB.

Both appear to be installed in CUPs. Both appear to be printing correctly with test page being reported as successfully printed.

However, the printers are not printing. No flashing lights. No indication that the printer is receiving anything from the computer.

If this was just happening to one printer, I would assume that there is an issue with drivers, but I think it may be an issue with my Ubuntu machine.

```
[elaine@evetech gutenprint-5.3.3]$ lpstat -v
device for HP_LaserJet_P1005: hp:/usb/HP_LaserJet_P1005?serial=BC1V02S
device for USB_Printer_1_with_status_readback_for_Canon_IJ: cnijbe2://Canon/?port=usbserial=071EF2
```